# Angular Material Date Picker not recognized

Tags: angular, angular-material

I get this :
[image]

Regardless of what I do. I have all my imports in the module.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule,
        TranslatePipeModule,
        FormsModule,
      MatFormFieldModule,
      MatInputModule,
      MatDatepickerModule,
      MatNativeDateModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [DynamicDataFilterComponent],
    providers: [],
    exports: [DynamicDataFilterComponent]
})
```

Comment: Is this Visual Studio Code? Can you provide more information please.

Comment: does it throw any errors when trying to run? or is just the squiggly lines?

Comment: @Juan This one does not throw any error but MAT-Chips throw an error.  this._chipInput?.setDescribedByIds is not a function